# PowerShell Scripts - I don't get disk info with Win32 LogicalDisk

Tags: windows, powershell, diskspace

My issue, I use Win32 LogicalDisk to get disk size info all servers except one server. 
I got empty disk size as following :

```
**Get-WMIObject  -ComputerName Servername Win32_LogicalDisk**
DeviceID     : C:
DriveType    : 3
ProviderName : 
FreeSpace    : 
Size         : 
VolumeName   : 

DeviceID     : E:
DriveType    : 3
ProviderName : 
FreeSpace    : 
Size         : 
VolumeName   : App
```

Everyone, please suggest me to fixed this issue.

**Note :** Last time I fixed it by restart this server and I can get disk size info but I can't restart it everytime when it's happening.

Thank you all

Comment: Not sure this is a programming issue. I'd healthcheck WMI on the server in question. `wmidiag` could be a good start mayhaps.

Comment: This is an issue with WMI, not PowerShell.

Comment: How can I check what is problem about WMI ? 

Sometime I got data, Sometime I don't get it.

Comment: @Waranonp Like I said, [wmidiag](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7684) is probably a good start.

Comment: @notjustme I'll check it thanks dude.